# Game Center show "No score"

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, game-center, leaderboard

I recently tried to add Game Center to my Sprite Kit Game, but it's not working properly.
So I am sending scores to the GC leaderboards, I receive no errors and the scores apprently send but I still see no scores listed in the leaderboards! The leaderboard itself is listed in Game Center there are just no scores.

**GameViewController**

```
import GameKit


class GameViewController: UIViewController, GKGameCenterControllerDelegate{



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let skView = self.view as! SKView
        let scene = GameScene(size: skView.bounds.size)
        scene.scaleMode = .AspectFit

        skView.presentScene(scene)
        authenticateLocalPlayer()

    }

    //Initiate GameCenter
    func authenticateLocalPlayer(){

        var localPlayer = GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer()

        localPlayer.authenticateHandler = {(viewController, error) -> Void in

            if (viewController != nil) {
                self.presentViewController(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }

            else {
                println((GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer().authenticated))
            }
        }

    }

    func gameCenterViewControllerDidFinish(gameCenterViewController: GKGameCenterViewController!)
    {
        gameCenterViewController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

**GameState**

```
import Foundation
import GameKit

class GameState {

    var score: Int
    var highScore: Int

    class var sharedInstance :GameState {
        struct Singleton {
            static let instance = GameState()
        }

        return Singleton.instance
    }

    init() {
        // Init
        score = 0
        highScore = 0

        // Load game state
        let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

        highScore = defaults.integerForKey("highScore")
    }

    func saveState() {
        // Update highScore if the current score is greater
        highScore = max(score, highScore)

        // Store in user defaults
        let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        defaults.setInteger(highScore, forKey: "highScore")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
    }



    func saveHighScore(high:Int64) {
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        //check if user is signed in
        if GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer().authenticated {

            var scoreReporter = GKScore(leaderboardIdentifier: "LeaderboardID")

            scoreReporter.value = Int64(highScore) //score variable here (same as above)

            var scoreArray: [GKScore] = [scoreReporter]


            GKScore.reportScores(scoreArray, withCompletionHandler: {(error : NSError!) -> Void in
                if error != nil {
                    println(error.description)
                }
            })

        }
    }
}
```

**EndGameScene**

```
class EndGameScene: SKScene, GKGameCenterControllerDelegate {

    func gameCenterViewControllerDidFinish(gameCenterViewController: GKGameCenterViewController!)
    {
        gameCenterViewController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

    }
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    var touch = touches as! Set<UITouch>
    var location = touch.first!.locationInNode(self)
    var node = self.nodeAtPoint(location)

    if (node.name == "gameCenter") {
        var vc = self.view?.window?.rootViewController
        var gc = GKGameCenterViewController()
        gc.gameCenterDelegate = self
        vc?.presentViewController(gc, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
```

How can I fix? Thanks and sorry for my English

Comment: According to https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/GameCenterOverview/GameCenterOverview.html GameCenter requires an application to be in the App Store. So I'd expect you'll be unable to actually use Game Center until release.

Although I'd expect Apple to provide some sort of test server like they do for in-app-purchases. But have you set up your signature, certificates etc.?

Comment: Does that mean there is no way to test to see if the game center works with the app until it is released?

Comment: @uliwitness You can test GameCenter in sandbox environment same as you test in-app purchases https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/TestingYourGameCenter-AwareGame/TestingYourGameCenter-AwareGame.html

Comment: @uliwitness- You are incorrect. Apple provides sandbox testing for Game Center during development. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnectGameCenter_Guide/TestingYourApp/TestingYourApp.html

Comment: @uliwitness All is setup well in iTunes connect and I activated "Sandbox Mode" on simulator and on my device.

Comment: @Meteius OK, if you have the test server turned on, that's not your issue.

Comment: @uliwitness So do you think that once sent the application, it will work properly or should I wait?

Comment: @Meteius No. I wouldn't risk shipping it untested.

Comment: @uliwitness You know how can I solve?

Comment: I believe you have to test this now through TestFlight and no more sandbox